# How to stop being notified by my un-deletable question

Tags: support, feature-request

I'll try to omit venting my frustration with the entire SE-verse here and just ask the question.

I asked a question.  The only responses to it were from people that had not read the question.  Decided the annoyance of the notifications outweighed the value to me in keeping the question around.  Tried to delete it.  System says that it cannot be deleted.

Ok, I suppose that's fair, but I should be allowed to ignore it and stop being notified.  Is that possible?  If not, why not?  Do I just have to delete my account in order to disassociate myself from the question?

Comment: The Question cannot be deleted because it has an upvoted Answer. The best post on disassociation is: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa which steps you through a "Contact" link at the bottom of each page.

Comment: That's probably a bit more than I was looking for.  In this case, I'm not concerned with attribution or anonymity; I'm just looking to not be notified of activity.  It sounds like that's not possible, so I guess this is more of a feature suggestion.

Comment: I haven't loaded your question into my brain, but I'm general, I'd encourage patience. Most of our community is interested in solving problems, so if you e done your best to make your question answerable, you may get a useful answer -- I should say, additional useful answers. Otherwise, the CM team may entertain a request to be disassociated from that post.